# K-lite Codec crashing issue

Tags: c#, video, mediaelement, codec, wmp

I have a C# windows form application in which I am playing videos one by one using WMP activex object and WPF MediaElement (I have included it using element host into windows forms). When application starts user selects either WMP or Media Element to play the videos. Then application starts the playing videos one by one from predefined local directory.

The video formats are almost all the leading formats like wmv, avi, mpg, mpeg, mp4, mkv, flv, mov, vob, 3gp. I am using K-lite codecs full pack so that all these formats can play in the player.

Now, the problem is that after installing the k-lite and my application everything works perfectly (All videos plays perfectly). But after sometime some videos stops playing in both the components. At that time I checked whether it plays in actual (native) windows media player or not but it does not play in it also. Then if I uninstalls the K-lite and installs it again, video starts playing both in my application as well as native WM Player. This behavior happens again after some time.

The time after it happens can be anything between hours to days and every time it happens with different video formats. Also I checked it with different hardware and the behavior is same. What could be this problem? Is it a components (WMP activex and Media element) problem? Is it really that codecs crashing issue? or is this issue of codecs conflict with graphics driver?

Also, I have disabled the hardware acceleration in registry.

Also, one thing I forgot to tell is that this screen

[image: WMP Initial Settings]

Apart from the K-lite codecs this is also a case. I don't understand why my WMP settings are getting lost and it asking me to do it again and again although I have kept windows updates off.

Thanks.

Comment: Borderline superuser question. Are you sure that nothing else is crashing out at the same time? Audio service? Video drivers? Any events in the windows event logs (application/system) that might be related?

Comment: I don't think so because VLC is able to play the same videos. And only thing that I do after this is uninstall and install the codecs again and it works for some unknown time.

Comment: These are easily verifiable. "I don't think so" doesn't smell of proper diagnostic reasoning here.

Comment: I said that because VLC is able to play the video and also audio is proper in it. But anyway I will confirm it.

Comment: OK, audio is probably fine. The event log might yield something though.

Comment: K-Lite installs a handful of codecs, which integrate themselves into system and alter its operation. One of them might easily be broken and crashing your app. It is debugging to reveal which exactly is the cause. Basically any codec pack might let you down in a similar way, you are always better off to install the codecs one by one, only those you really need and you are confident in.